# Limits of length for the expansion of * in Bash?

Tags: bash, command-line, command-line-arguments

In Bash

```
echo *
```

is almost equivalent to `ls`.

You can do things like

```
echo */*-out/*.html > all-my-html-files-on-one-line
```

Since `*` is a **command line argument** then there should be a limit on the length.

What is that limit?

Is the limit different between `echo` the Bash command and `/bin/echo` the program?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The shell does not limit this

You can see the limit for your system with (run on my 64bit linux:)

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX
2097152
```

See this very informational page http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/

Answer (score 3):

I believe the command line limit is the value of ARG_MAX which you can see with

```
getconf ARG_MAX
```

This is not a bash variable, which would suggest that the limit is the same for `echo` in bash and `/bin/echo`.

Comment: `echo` doesn't execute any external commands, so it's not affected by ARG_MAX. Try it out `/bin/echo $(seq $(getconf ARG_MAX))` will fail but `echo $(seq $(getconf ARG_MAX))` will probably succeed.