# How to awk or grep a variable, without using echo?

Tags: performance, bash, awk, grep

I'm working with large variables and to speedup my script I'd like to `awk` or `grep` a variable without using `echo/printf`

what I've tried:

```
awk "/test/ {for(i=1; i<=100; i++) {getline; print}}" "$var"
awk: fatal: cannot open file `<<$var content>>' for reading (No such file or directory)

grep -A 100 test "$var"
grep: `<<$var content>>': No such file or directory
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send string to stdin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541109/send-string-to-stdin)

Comment: You should look hard at whether large variables are really the best way to do your work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In bash you can redirect from a variable to stdin using the one-line heredoc:

```
awk "/test/ {for(i=1; i<=100; i++) {getline; print}}" <<< "$var"
```

Comment: I do not think you should remove the quotes.  `<<< "$var"`

Comment: @Jotne AFAIK the heredoc body is treated as a string: interpolation will be performed, but shell injection (like with `var="a; rm -rf `") will not work. Anyway, a pair of `""` does not hurt, so I added them.

Comment: Without the double quotes, you get a single line of input — the newlines in the input are flattened into spaces (and multiple spaces are flattened into single spaces, etc).  From the question, it appears that `$var` might have more than 100 lines after the line containing `test` — so the double quotes are necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you, you have a multi-line string stored in the shell variable `var` and you'd like to print 100 lines from the line containing `test` in that string inclusive. With GNU awk that'd be:

```
$ awk -v var="$var" 'BEGIN{ printf "%s", gensub(/.*(test([^\n]*\n){100}).*/,"\\1","",var) }'
```

e.g. to print "test" plus the 2 or 3 lines after it, inclusive:

```
$ echo "$var"
abc
def
test
ghi
klm
nop

$ awk -v var="$var" 'BEGIN{ printf "%s", gensub(/.*(test([^\n]*\n){2}).*/,"\\1","",var) }'
test
ghi

$ awk -v var="$var" 'BEGIN{ printf "%s", gensub(/.*(test([^\n]*\n){3}).*/,"\\1","",var) }'
test
ghi
klm
```

With other awks you can use match() + substr() to get the same result.

Comment: I'm getting `/usr/bin/awk: Argument list too long`

Comment: Then you are not using the script I posted as `awk` has zero args in my script. Note that on Solaris /usr/bin/awkis old, broken awk which should never be used. If you're on Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk.