# loop over input in C-code and write data to different files using terminal at once

Tags: c

I wrote a C code which extracts data from a binary file which has size around 1 GB. There are 101 (0 to 100)configurations and the C code extracts data for a selected configuration and writes the output in a file. To compile the C code, I give user defined configuration number like this in the terminal:

```
gcc binary2textperconfig.c -o f.out
./f.out proton-p000-1.bin out1.txt
```

Then it asks for configuration number:

```
Enter the configuration number:
```

After that the data is written in file "out0.txt". Now I want to run this code for all 101 configurations and write those data to files "out0.txt", "out1.txt",...., "out100.txt" etc. I don't know how to do this without typing the configuration numbers 101 times in the terminal. Could any one please help me? Here is my C-code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<complex.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_gamma.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>


typedef double complex  dcomplex;


//Data is converted to Bigendian using io-general

double constructfloat(char bytes[sizeof(double)/2],  int order)
{
    double dRes;
    char *pc;
    int i;

    if (order == 0)
        for(i=0, pc = (char*) &dRes; i<=sizeof(double)-1 ; i++, pc++)
            (*pc) = bytes[i];
    else
        for(i=sizeof(double)-1, pc = (char*) &dRes; i>=0; i--, pc++)
            (*pc) = bytes[i];

    return dRes;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){



    int configcount = 101;
    int mcount = 14;
    int tcount = 64;
    int d1count = 4;
    int d2count = 4;
    int pcount = 45;


    int userci;
    int usermi;
    int userpi;


    // number of complex numbers per configuration
    int unitcountperconfig =(mcount*tcount*d1count*d2count*pcount);


    // initialize loop index variables
    int ci = 0; //config
    int mi = 0; //mass
    int ti = 0;
    int d1i = 0;
    int d2i = 0;
    int pi = 0; //momentum

    // for holding the result of read operation ( how many units have been read)
    int result;

    // for holding the data read from file
    char * cbuff;


    // input file handle from where binary data is read
    FILE * fin = fopen(argv[1],"rb");

    // if the input file cannot be read for reading, close opened file handles, show an error message to the user, and exit
    if (fin==NULL)
    {
        fputs ("Error opening input file\n",stderr);
        exit (1);
    }

    FILE * fout = fopen(argv[2],"wt");

    // if the output file cannot be opened for writing, close opened file handles, show an error message to the user, and exit
    if (fout==NULL)
    {
        fclose(fin);
        fputs ("Error opening output file\n",stderr);
        exit (1);
    }


    // take input from the user
    // take input from the user
    printf("Enter the configuration number: ");
    scanf("%d",&userci);

    // allocate memory to contain the chunk of data for a time slice:
    cbuff = (char*)malloc(sizeof(dcomplex)*unitcountperconfig );

    // show error message and exit if memory allocation failed
    if(cbuff == NULL)
    {
        fputs("Buffer allocation failed.", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    // variable to hold a complex number read from the file
    dcomplex aComplexNumber;

    dcomplex sumpertimeslice[tcount];


    // loop on time slices
    for( ci = 0;  ci< configcount ; ci++){

        // index of the complex number being read
        unsigned int cNumberIdx = 0;

        // debugging message
        printf("reading data for configuration: %d\n",ci);

        // perform read operation to read the desired chunk of data
        result = fread(cbuff,  sizeof(char),  sizeof(dcomplex)*unitcountperconfig, fin );


        // if size of data successfully read is not equal to what we wanted to read, notify the user and exit
        if (result != sizeof(dcomplex)*unitcountperconfig) {
            fputs ("data reading error\n",stderr);
            exit (3);
        }

        double realP;
        double imagP;// variable to hold real and imaginary part of the complex number


        double realPSum;
        double imagPSum;// variable to hold sum of real and sum of imaginary part of the current sum per time slice


            for (mi =0; mi< mcount ; mi++){

                for (ti =0; ti< tcount ; ti++){



                // array to hold trace for each time slice
                sumpertimeslice[ti] = 0.0 + 0.0*_Complex_I;

                    for (d1i =0; d1i < d1count ; d1i++){
                        for (d2i =0; d2i < d2count ; d2i++){
                            for (pi =0; pi < pcount ; pi++){
                            aComplexNumber = constructfloat( &cbuff[cNumberIdx], 0 ) + constructfloat( &cbuff[cNumberIdx+ ((int)sizeof(dcomplex))/2 ], 0 )*_Complex_I;
                if (ci== userci)
                {
            cNumberIdx += (int)sizeof(dcomplex);
                            if (cimag(aComplexNumber)>0)
                            {fprintf( fout, "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%e+%ei\n" ,ci+1, mi+1,ti+1, d1i+1,d2i+1,pi+1,creal( aComplexNumber ),cimag( aComplexNumber ) );}
                            else
                            {fprintf( fout, "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%e%ei\n" ,ci+1, mi+1,ti+1, d1i+1,d2i+1,pi+1,creal(  aComplexNumber ),cimag( aComplexNumber ) );}
                }


                            }               
                        }           
                    }


                }           
            }

            }



    // free the allocated memory    
    free(cbuff);

    // close the opened file handles
    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);
    //fclose(complexNumberFileP);

}
```

Comment: Would the configuration number be given an a sequence?

Comment: Yes...the configuration numbers are in sequence. from 0 to 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [seq](/questions/tagged/seq) utility to generate a list of number between 0 & 100, and [send it as a string to stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6541109/438117).

```sh
for CNUMBER in $(seq 0 100); do
    ./f.out proton-p000-1.bin out${CNUMBER}.txt <<< "${CNUMBER}"
done
```

or

```sh
for CNUMBER in $(seq 0 100); do
    echo $CNUMBER | ./f.out proton-p000-1.bin out${CNUMBER}.txt
done
```