# How can I compile a LESS string using lessc

Tags: php, unix

Here is an example of how to compile a **file**:

```
$lines = [];
exec("lessc $file", $lines, $status);
$output = implode("", $lines);
```

I would like to compile just a string ideally without creating a temporary file, writing to it, and then calling exec to compile that file. My unix skills aren't that great so I tried variations of this which doesn't work:

```
$lines = [];
exec("lessc < \"$string\"", $lines, $status);
$output = implode("", $lines);
```

Comment: You should probably check this out: http://leafo.net/lessphp/

Comment: You need to substitute the filename parameter then certainly, if not with `-` then `/dev/stdin`. Also either escape the $string properly, or use proc_open.

Comment: @pNre I'd rather trust the official binary keeping up with the current version of LESS. LessPHP doesn't even indicate which version of LESS it supports, with their last commit 4 months ago, and 166 open issues. Good suggestion though, it would have been perfect if it was actively maintained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `lessc --help` in the console, you will that:

> usage: lessc [option option=parameter ...]  [destination]
>
> If source is set to `-' (dash or hyphen-minus), input is read from
>   stdin.

The above enable you to run for instance (see also: [Send string to stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541109/send-string-to-stdin)):

```
echo "@color:red; p{color:@color;}" | lessc -
```

or

```
lessc - <<< "@color:red; p{color:@color;}"
```

And indeed [less.php](https://github.com/oyejorge/less.php) can:

```
$parser = new Less_Parser();
$parser->parse( '@color: #4D926F; #header { color: @color; } h2 { color: @color; }' );
$css = $parser->getCss();
```