# IBM MQ 8.0, How to provide username and password to amqsget as command line parameters

Tags: ibm-mq

I have an error popping up after upgrading to IBM MQ 8.0 from 7.5 reason being -

*In MQ 8.0, a new function is introduced that requires MQ administrators using remote access to supply the userid and password. When the userid and password are not supplied or the password is incorrect*

Error: 2035 Code : 2
The queue manager is configured to require a user ID and password, but none was supplied.

The problem is described better in this [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21680930).
There are three scenarios that are talked about. My solution would fall in  Scenario A) MQ samples: Provide the user and password to the MQ client application

I'm trying to read from the MQ using a program. Is there a way I can pass the username and password as part of the command line parameters rather than inputting it when prompted. Because this exe is invoked by my program.

```
$ amqsputc qName qMgr
```

Comment: If modifying the sample application is an option for you, modify the sample to accept userid and password also from command line: Example: amqsputc qName qMgr userId password.

Comment: amqsput or amqsget in version 8.0 doesn't support that

Comment: Didn't get you, what is not supported in v8.0?

Answer (score 4):

IBM provides a client-side channel security exit called [`mqccred`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q114370_.htm?lang=en) to perform this task.  The full documentation is at the link provided but in general it requires the following:

- Specify the exit in a CCDT file.
- Configure the exit by placing ID and password in an ini file
- Execute the [`runmqccred`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q114380_.htm?lang=en) command against the ini file to obfuscate the passwords.
- Make sure the ini file is set so that world- and group-read are disabled.

Note that Java/JMS programs can easily be modified and the exit is intended mainly for programs using the native C API or that are compiled on top of that.

Answer (score 4):

If your client can't (yet) supply the username/password, you can disable the username/password requirement in the MQ 8.0 queue manager:

1. Start **MQ Explorer**
2. Go to **Queue Managers** → *<your_queue_manager>* → **Authentication information**
3. Click "**Show system objects**" icon at top right

[image: MQ Explorer / Authentication information / Show system objects]

4. `SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS` → **User ID + Password** → **Check client connections** → Select **Optional**

[image: MQ SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS / User ID + Password / Check client connections / Optional]

5. Right-click on your queue manager → **Security** → **Refresh Authorization Service...**

[image: Right-click on queue manager, Security, Refresh Authorization Service]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried providing the password with heredoc, like this?

```
amqsputc qName qMgr <<< "passwd"
```

[Send string to stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541109/send-string-to-stdin)

Comment: I tried. That didn't work. I get an error:  << is unexpected at this time.

Answer (score 0):

The MQ samples were updated to allow a user ID to be specified and, if set, to prompt you to enter your password:
[MQ Bitesize Blogging](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/bitesize_blogging_mq_v8_samples_can_use_user_id_and_password)

Some take a new optional command line parameter [-u User], others check for the presence of the MQSAMP_USER_ID environment variable.