# How do I print a number with bash for shell script?

Tags: bash

Sorry this is a very easy question, how do I print 0 from a shell script? My program is doing scanf for a number, I want the script to enter 0.

I tried echo 0, it doesnt seem to work.

```
#!/bin/bash
make clean
ls -l
cat udpserver.c
make
ls -l
./udpserver
sleep 2
echo 0 | udpserver
sleep 2
echo 0 | udpserver
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send string to stdin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541109/send-string-to-stdin)

Comment: @BenjaminW. See his edited question, it's not as simple as the duplicate.

Comment: Don'Ät spam tags. This is not related to C.

Comment: @Barmar Now it's different...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a pipe to send input to a program that you started previously, you have to use it when starting the program. If you want to pipe multiple commands to it, put them in a subshell.

```
(sleep 2; echo 0; sleep 2; echo 0) | ./udpserver
```

Comment: Or `( echo line1 ; echo line2 ) | yourProg` or `printf "line1\nline2\n" | yourProg` - the possibilities are almost endless :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo I didn't mention that because I said that using a here-doc is best for multiple lines.

Comment: I dont get it, where am I going wrong here? Heres my script:

Comment: @sublimesummer Don't put code in comments. Edit your question to show what you tried.

Comment: Barmar, wasn't criticising your answer (in fact I voted for it), but there are situations where a heredoc doesn't cut it. Specifically, if the input has to be more complex, such as `( expr $bytes / 1024 ) | processKilobytes`. The OPs question is nowhere *near* that level of complexity as you rightly point out.

Comment: @paxdiablo Yeah, I didn't want to go into all the details of providing computed input for this question.

Comment: @paxdiablo Now that he's edited the question, he does need more complicated answer.