# Get local variable in terraform console

Tags: terraform

Is there any way to get local variables within Terraform console?

```
> local.name
unknown values referenced, can't compute value
```

Seems like Terraform console allows only to check input variables and module output variables.

```
> var.in
2

> module.abc.out
3
```

Configuration file examples:

```
# main.tf

locals {
  name = 1
}

variable "in" {
  value = 2
}

module "abc" {
  source "path/to/module"
}

# path/to/module/main.tf

output "out" {
  value = 3
}
```

Comment: Where is the local value set from? Please elaborate.

Comment: @mithilesh.kunal Edited the question to give more context ‍♂️

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like this is not possible in Terraform v0.11.x, but will be in v0.12 as described in this issue ticket:

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/18413

HTH!

Answer (score 20):

This should work in recent Terraform releases.

```
$ terraform version
Terraform v1.0.5

$ terraform console
> local.name
1
> var.in
2
```

And it can be [scripted](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/console#scripting) (non-interactive) using Bash [here string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6541324/86967), for example.

```bash
$ terraform console <<<local.name
1
```

This is might be really useful for custom tooling, and can even be quite sophisticated.

```bash
$ terraform console <<<terraform.workspace
"default"

$ terraform console <<<local.credentials[local.stack].username
"user1234"
```

---

The tested 'main.tf'

```
locals {
  name = 1
  stack = terraform.workspace
  credentials={ 
    default: {username:"user1234",password:"1234",endpoint:"http://localhost"}
  }
}

variable in {
  default = 2
}
```

Comment: Why on Earth doesn't `terraform console` have a feature to list all known data?

Answer (score 2):

There is no [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) on terraform console still as on today(December 2021)

But there is a [strongly upvoted request for that, see here on github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/19034). If you feel appropriate, you may also go there and upvote.

For me I just wanted to get some items from a list.

For the first item, I could use the [element](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/element.html) function  and do this.

```
element(["apple", "banana", "pine apple", "grape", "strawberry"], 0)
```

I get back "apple".

And if want the last item, I have to do the following, using [length](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/length.html) function

```
element(["apple", "banana", "pine apple", "grape", "strawberry"], 
length(["apple", "banana", "pine apple", "grape", "strawberry"])-1)
```

I get back "strawberry".

Since there is code repetition here, I was look for something like this, to define a variable and use it.

```
var fruits = ["apple", "banana", "pine apple", "grape", "strawberry"]
element(fruits, length(fruits)-1)
```

**This is just not working**.

So I ended up defining a variable in a file called main.tf as follows.

```
variable fruits {
  default = ["apple", "banana", "pine apple", "grape", "strawberry"]
}
```

Launched terraform console.

Now I can use it as follows.

```
element(var.fruits, length(var.fruits)-1)
```

Some of the relevant examples you may want to look at [from my Repo](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/AzureWithTerraform)

- [Terraform-console-lists](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/AzureWithTerraform/tree/main/iac/800140-terraform-console-lists)
- [Terraform-console-splat-intro](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/AzureWithTerraform/tree/main/iac/1400100-terraform-console-splat-intro)
- [Output-foreach-console-two-input-vars](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/AzureWithTerraform/tree/main/iac/1400500-output-foreach-console-two-input-vars)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [terraform-repl](https://github.com/paololazzari/terraform-repl), an open source terraform console wrapper written in bash. Among other things, it provides tab completion and it also allows you to view all objects of a certain type (e.g. all `locals`).

---

Given `main.tf`:

```
locals {
  a = "foo"
  b = {"nums": [
    1
  ]}
}
```

then:

```bash
$ terraform-repl
> local
[
  {
    "a": "foo",
    "b": {
      "nums": [
        1
      ]
    }
  }
]
> local.<TAB>
local.a  local.b.nums[0]
> local.b.<TAB>
> local.b.nums[0]
```