# Correct way to assign regex replace to a variable in bash

Tags: bash, perl

I am trying to assign a variable to the result of a regex substitution in bash. For instance, when I run

`echo $initialvar | perl -pe 's/.+(Some_Dir\/)(.+)/\2/'`

I get the desired output from the `echo`. How would I assign a `newvar` to the resulting output?

I've tried:

```
newvar= "$($initialvar | perl -pe 's/.+(Some_Dir\/)(.+)/\2/')"
newvar= echo $initialvar | perl -pe 's/.+(Some_Dir\/)(.+)/\2/'
```

but none of them work

Comment: `newvar=$(perl -pe 's/.+(Some_Dir\/)(.+)/$2/' <<< "$initialvar")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your question, it seems to consist of two challenges: One being assigning the output of running a command to a BASH variable, and the other being piping the content of a variable to the standard input of a Perl program.

## One

```
foo=$(bar)
```

runs `bar` and saves its output to the BASH variable `$foo`.

## [The other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541109/send-string-to-stdin)

Any of

```
echo "$foo" | bar
bar <(echo "$foo")
bar <<< "$foo"
```

runs `bar` with the content of `$foo` piped to its standard input

## Combining the two

```
baz=$(bar <<< "$foo")
```

sets `$baz` to the value produced by `bar` having the content of `$foo` sent to its standard input.

---

Secondly, a few Perl-related suggestions peripherally related to your question:

I might instead use `perl -nE`:

- `-n` will loop through each line like `-p`, but won't print by default.
- `-E` will evaluate like `-e`, but with experimental features like `say` enabled.

You can avoid escaping the slash in `Some_Dir/` by using another separator, e.g. `s!...!...!` or `m!...!`. Instead of replacing with `s//`, since you're just printing "Some_Dir/" if it matches, you might as well go and do that directly:

```
perl -nE 'say (m!Some_Dir/! ? "Some_Dir/" : $_)'
```

So:

```
newvar=$(perl -nE 'say (m!Some_Dir/! ? "Some_Dir/" : $_)' <<< "$initialvar")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use either of the following:

```
newvar=$(echo "$initialvar" | perl -pe 's/.+(Some_Dir\/)(.+)/\2/')
newvar=`echo "$initialvar" | perl -pe 's/.+(Some_Dir\/)(.+)/\2/'`
```

Comment: Maybe point out that the backtick syntax is discouraged as obsolescent.