# Arguments of fortran program in bash

Tags: bash

I run a fortran program with bash:

```
#!/bin/sh
./program
```

and the program give three questions. How to give answers/arguments into bash script?

I tried:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "1 0 3,1.01" | program
```

but the error is command not found. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send string to stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541109/send-string-to-stdin)

Comment: Cross-site duplicate (same author): https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/516538/118235 – please don't ask identical questions on multiple Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are lacking the path.

```
echo "1 0 3,1.01" | ./program
```

Maybe you should have newlines between the answers, though?

```
printf "1\n0\n3,1.01\n" | ./program
```

A much better design would be for your Fortran program to accept its input as command-line arguments. Without the program's source, I can't say how to change it; but then you could say

```
./program 1 0 3,1.01
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In the first and second command I have a problem with the third argument that consists of more numbers. In the third command the question in terminal althrough appear.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand, could you rephrase the problem?

Comment: Like I wrote in the answer already, the third option requires you to make changes to your Fortran program.

Comment: There is  mistake: `At line 58 of file program.f (unit = 5, file = 'stdin')
Fortran runtime error: End of file` . I use a command: `echo "0 0 4281,4503,1.01" | ./program` . `4281,4503,1.01` is exactly what I write to terminal when a program runs.

Comment: Did you try with newlines between the numbers instead of spaces? Again, this is very hard to debug without access to at least a tiny part of your Fortran code -- what inputs exactly does it require, in what format? Try to boil this down to a [mcve] and maybe post a new question if it's a lot different from what you already posted here.

Comment: I tried to write newlines between the numbers instead of spaces, but there was an error. I replace it in code of program. Thank you