# Restore .bak files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I ran a perl script using

```
perl -p -i.bak -e "..." *.sh dir/*.sh
```

This created a copy of every file like

```
script.sh
script.sh.bak
```

I now want to restore from the `.bak` files. How can I do this easily?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for file in *.sh.bak dir/*.sh.bak; do cp "$file" "${file//.bak}"; done
```

Or you could use `mv` instead of `cp`.

Comment: Op De Cirkel: Why do you say it won't work? I believe the shell can handle any amount of files as the result of wildcard expansion; it's when you try to pass a long list to another process that `ARG_MAX` could bite you.

Comment: @OpDeCirkel: [`ARG_MAX` doesn't apply to shell builtins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461227/limits-of-length-for-the-output-of-in-bash)

Comment: @tripleee: You are correct. See my comment to Op De Cirkel above.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson You are right, ARG_MAX does not apply to built-ins....Good to know

Answer (score 2):

`find -name '*.bak'|sed 's:.bak$::'|xargs -n 1 -I % cp %.bak %`

Comment: That won't work if you have filenames which include newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this fix.

I've been using a combo the code below to fix an 'eval(base64_decode' in Joomla sites.

find: 
    grep -lr --include=*.php "eval(base64_decode" ./

remove: 
    grep -lr --include=.php "eval(base64_decode" ./ | xargs sed -i.bak 's/eval(base64_decode[^;];/\n/g'

undo: 
    find -name '*.bak'|sed 's:.bak$::'|xargs -n 1 -I % cp %.bak %