# Flipping every other picture in a directory

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of pictures that I want to print, but in order for them to print out correctly every other picture needs to be flipped horizontally. Now, the pictures are all png files and are labeled `"Foo 001.png"`, `"Foo 002.png"`. I am thinking that all I need to do is look at the part of the string that has the number, convert it to an integer, do `n%2==0` to check if it is even, and flip it if it is even.

I don't know if there is a convenient way to convert from a string to an integer using bash or what I would use to flip the picture.

Comment: Nah, just have a variable that you keep on toggling as you iterate over the files, no dependency on file naming convention then.  `X=0 ; ... ; do X=$((1-$X)) ; if [ $X -eq 1 ] ; then ... fi; ... done`

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you want to flip 1/2 images ? By flip, do you mean rotate ?

Comment: @vladr That would probably be easier, but how do I know what order the files will be iterated over in? Would it be alphabetical?

Comment: @russjohnson09 `ls`, `glob` etc. will do it alphabetically.  It's up to you to come up with a properly sorted list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a toggling variable to flip every other image in a list.

```
X=0

cat filenames | while read -r filename ; do
  if [ $X -eq 1 ] ; then
    # flip $filename
  fi
  # print $filename
  X=$((1-$X))
done
```

You may replace `cat filenames` above with `ls -1 *.jpg` to print `*.jpg` files in alphabetical order, or [`ls -1v` to version-sort them](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Details-about-version-sort.html#Details-about-version-sort), a way that does not require the sequence numbers in the filenames to be zero-padded.

If there are thousands of files, a combination of `ls` (no wildcards) and `grep` or one of `find` and `sort` can be used instead of the above in order to avoid blowing the [`ARG_MAX`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461227/limits-of-length-for-the-output-of-in-bash) limit.

Answer (score 1):

Since bash is much better with strings than numbers, my first thought would be

```
flip Foo\ *{0,2,4,6,8}.png
```

where `flip` is whatever command you're using to flip the pictures.

This assumes that the command can accept multiple filenames. If not, you can use a loop:

```
for f in Foo\ *{0,2,4,6,8}.png; do flip "$f"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you want to flip 1/2 png image ? If yes, then :

```
convert -flip "Foo *{0,2,4,6,8,10}.png"
```

or if you have too much files :

```
# making an array of files
files=( *.png )

# C style for loop (iterating 2 by 2)
for ((i=0; i< ${#files[@]}; i+=2)) {
     # fliping the image
     convert -flip "${files[i]}"
}
```

convert command is part of well known [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) library.